# Static HTML+JavaScript document to encrypt passwords using my OpenPGP public key

Tags: open-source, web-apps, javascript, encryption, pgp

When I need the password for an online account of my client, and this client doesn’t use OpenPGP, we typically use the telephone (which is bothersome, and unencrypted).

I’m looking for a solution (free/libre/open source) that allows my client to encrypt the password with my OpenPGP public key.

I don’t want to run server-side code, and I don’t want the client to have to install something, so I’m thinking of a static HTML+JavaScript page hosted on my server.

Is this possible? Or would the encryption take too long?

#### Desired workflow

1. Open `https://my-server.example.com/secrets.html`.
2. Optionally: download this document and/or activate the browser’s offline mode.
3. Enter the password into the text area and press the "Encrypt" button.
4. Copy the encrypted text.

Now my client can paste the encrypted text into a regular email.

Comment: Would a [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/) work? Default workflow would be a little different, it would probably be easier to send you the encrypted file, unless some sort of plugin to encrypt single tiddlers was used

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Would it be [this "Encryption" feature](https://tiddlywiki.com/static/Encryption.html)? If I understand it correctly, it uses symmetric encryption, so I would need to know the password which the client uses to encrypt their secret/password -- and we would again have the problem how to securely transmit a password. If it’s possible to use asymmetric encryption, or if it’s possible to set a TiddlyWiki up such that the client can enter content without having to know the password to encrypt it, then it could be a good solution.

Comment: Ah you are right, never mind that